# Forma correcta de pasar una función como parámetro de otra en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web

Tengo una duda, en JavaScript necesito pasar una función como parametro dentro de otra, sin embargo no tengo bien clara la sintaxis para hacerlo, mi código se trata de pasar diversas coordenadas, para posterior procesamiento, es más o menos así:

```
    var delay = 100;
    var nextAddress = 0;
    var origen = 18.073479 + ',' + -96.762471;
    var destinos = [];

    for(let x = 0;x< 20;x++){ //Rellenar array de Coordenadas, se obtendrán de una BD
        destinos.push(25.671950 + ',' + -100.328095);
    }


    function theNext() {

        if (nextAddress < destinos.length) {
          setTimeout('calculateAndDisplayRoute(origen, destinos[nextAddress], theNext)', delay);
          nextAddress++;
        }

    }
```

Es en la parte del setTimeout donde tengo la duda si ¿el primer parámetro lo debo pasar todo como un string, de la siguiente manera?:

```
setTimeout('calculateAndDisplayRoute(origen, destinos[nextAddress], theNext)', delay);
```

o ¿Debo concatenar los parametros de la función que pasa como primer parametro, de la siguiente manera?:

```
setTimeout('calculateAndDisplayRoute(' + origen + ',' + destinos[nextAddress] + ', theNext)', delay);
```

O por último, ¿debo pasar el primer parametro sin ser de tipo string?, de la siguiente manera:

```
setTimeout(calculateAndDisplayRoute(origen, destinos[nextAddress], theNext), delay);
```

En este último, provoca que la función theNext se repita demasiadas veces.

Espero me puedan ayudar a despejar esa duda, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función `setTimeout` de esta forma

```
setTimeout(calculateAndDisplayRoute, delay, origen, destinos[nextAddress], theNext);
```

Después del parametro de retraso, puedes añadir parámetros opcionales que se pasaran a la función una vez que sea ejecuta.

[Aquí la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Answer (score 0):

Debería ser como la ultima opción que pusiste

```
setTimeout(calculateAndDisplayRoute(origen, destinos[nextAddress], theNext), delay);
```

Comment: El problema es que cuando desde mi funcion calculateAndDisplayRoute,, vuelvo a llamar a theNext se ejecutiva miles de veces

Comment: podrías agregar el código de la función calculateAndDisplayRoute?